# how to call DropDownList's onselectedindexchanged event from CreateUserWizard->WizardStep

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using CreateUserWizard and added additional WizardStep for user additional details.
I am using one dropdownlist. value has been filled from DB in dropdownlist. 
Now, when I will change the value in dropdownlist. I want to chekc/uncheck the one checkbox based on it's value in DB for selected dropdownlist value.
For that i want to call onselectedindexchanged event of dropdownlist.

How to fire onselectedindexchanged event?

Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What have u tried and why its not firing

Comment: I have manually added onselectedindexchanged in codebehind to get value of checkbox for selected dropdownlist value.

Comment: dont write manually in property menu of item there are tab of event on right hand where all events are listed double click on event u want

Answer (score 0):

Dont add `onselectedindexchanged` manually

All event for element are listed in event tab on right hand side

[image: Dropdownlist event]

Your code should look like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

In cs file

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }
```

Important Note

Remove the `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` in the CreateUserWizard control

Comment: I am creating a new user using CreateUserWizard. now I have added additional WizardStep to add additional details of user. And I have use this dropdown list and checkbox also in this WizardStep. When I select property of dropdownlist. but not showing Event tab.So i unable to add event from there. So, i have added it manually.

Comment: can u just copy paste onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" and have given event, though u can change event name. check for spelling mistakes and its case sensitive

Comment: In Aspx file:
<asp:DropDownList ID="drplstUser" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="false" onselectedindexchanged="drpFaculty_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                </asp:DropDownList> 

In Cs File
 



protected void drpFaculty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Code Here....
}

Comment: Yes, it is not wokring. may be dropdownlist in wizardstep. is there any solution?

Comment: check update Remove the ViewStateMode="Disabled" in the CreateUserWizard control

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

drag a dropdownlist control on your aspx page and add selectedindexchanged event, test it properly, now cut the control and paste it inside WizardStep.

I hope it works.